# Paging3 with Hilt : An instance of PagingSource was re-used

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, android-paging-3

I provide `PagingSource` class by using `Dagger-Hilt`.

**RemoteDatasourceModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RemoteDataSourceModule {

 @Provides
 fun provideListRemotePagingSource(
     api: ApiService,
 ): ListRemotePagingSource {
     return ListRemotePagingSource(api = ApiService)
 }
}
```

**ListRepositoryImpl.kt**

```
class ListRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(.
  private val remotePagingSource: ListRemotePagingSource
 ): ListRepository {

 override fun getListPagingData(): Flow<PagingData<Content>> {
     return Pager(
         config = PagingConfig(
             pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
             enablePlaceholders = false
         ),
         pagingSourceFactory = {
             remotePagingSource
         }
     ).flow
 }

 companion object {
     const val DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 20
 }
}
```

But when the PagingDataAdapter is refreshed by `refresh()`,
suddenly, i've just ran into this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: An instance of PagingSource was re-used when Pager expected to create a new instance. Ensure that the pagingSourceFactory passed to Pager always returns a new instance of PagingSource.`
So, i thought it would be the problem of `Hilt`.
Therefore, i changed the `ListRepositoryImpl.kt` like below.

```
class ListRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(.
    private val remotePagingSource: ListRemotePagingSource,
    private val api: ApiService
   ): ListRepository {

  override fun getListPagingData(): Flow<PagingData<Content>> {
  return Pager(
      config = PagingConfig(
          pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
          enablePlaceholders = false
      ),
      pagingSourceFactory = {
          ListRemotePagingSource(api)
      }
    ).flow
  }

  companion object {
    const val DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 20
  }
}
```

In this code, `ListRemotePagingSource` class always is created newly. 
It worked very well. But i don't get it why the way using `Hilt` didn't work...
I even didn't use any `@Singleton` annotation on the `provideListRemotePagingSource()` in `RemoteDatasourceModule.kt` to create new instance every time. I know that `@Provides` annotation create new instance. Am i wrong?? I hope someone tells me.. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem related to Hilt as it is so much related to your implementation of Paging. Imagine if you were implementing the code generated by Hilt which would inject `ListRemotePagingSource` into your constructor. Regardless of what value you pass for `remotePagingSource`, you cannot make `pagingSourceFactory()` return a new instance each time it is invoked.

In the first example you have:

```
pagingSourceFactory = {
    remotePagingSource
}
```

and in the second:

```
pagingSourceFactory = {
    ListRemotePagingSource(api)
}
```

when `pagingSourceFactory()` is invoked, it will return two new instances in the second example, but in the first example it will always return whatever value is passed to `remotePagingSource`.

`PagingDataAdapter.refresh()` is not a repository / hilt / lifecycle method that would re-create your entire repository. It is a Paging function that eventually invokes `pagingSourceFactory`.

You definitely want the second implementation every time, but if you want to use Hilt to inject Paging, you cannot just inject a single instance of `PagingSource` that would be returned every time on refresh(). You can provide `pagingSourceFactory` or better yet `Pager` itself, which is probably what I would recommend instead.